# Does accelerating ice produce electromagnetic radiation?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, ice

There are at least two parts in this question. First one is does the interior of the ice produce radiation when it is accelerated? I guess it does not "because it is electrically neutral". But really, why not? I thought only the magnetic field is divergence-free. Second part is about the sides of the ice exposed to the environment. Now I believe it is not electrically neutral and that allows other molecules to join and make ice grow. So if this block of ice is accelerated forward, I do not see why the exterior could not produce EM waves. Please note that I am only interested in radiation produced by the translational acceleration, not thermal effects.

Comment: Downvotes are likely because of one part you said which is not so clear.  This part is not clear in particular:
"Also does the interior of ice produce radiation when it is accelerated? I guess it does not because it is electrically neutral. But really, why not? I thought only the magnetic field is divergence-free."

Comment: I would just simplify the question and rephrase the whole thing to:  "does acceleration of ice produce radiation? and if it does is it produced by charges on the interior or exterior of the ice".

Comment: I would appreciate you limit your contribution to your answer and do not edit my post yourself. I read your comments already.

Answer (score 0):

**Does accelerating ice produce electromagnetic radiation?**

This is a very interesting question.
**Yes, it will certainly emit some radiation.** But answering exactly how much is not an easy question and it depends on the structure and size of the ice. But that's fine, let's try to think about the problem and get an understanding of it in general.

Since $H_2O$ has a dipole moment, if the molecules were perfectly aligned the total dipole moment is just the sum of the individual dipoles. The [sum of  homogeneously polarized material will produce an external surface charge](https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/elmat_en/kap_3/backbone/r3_1_1.html):

[image]

You can read more about this (which is part of your question) in chapter 4 of Griffiths' Electricity and Magnetism book.

In your case of ice, the structure of the molecules is fixed - so we end up not just getting "dipoles" but more complicated "multipoles".

Now here **ice certainly has an advantage over water**, which is that the ice can form a relatively **fixed molecular orientation**. Any collection of charges will form some kind of "multipole" and accelleration of that pole will create some kind of radiation. So let's see if there's any research that looks into the polarizability of ice molecules.

I found a [paper from 1965](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2415391) looked into the total magnitude and direction of the e-field by a collection of 85 molecules in ice:

[image]

They show that **the entire structure of ice has a total dipole moment**. Now for a good approximation, you just need to plug in their value for the dipole strength to the [standard equations for the electric-field with an oscillating dipole](http://www.physics.sfsu.edu/%7Elea/courses/ugrad/460notes5.PDF). And voila, accelerated ice emitting electromagnetic radiation:

[image]

And there you have it! Now all you need to do is figure out how to shake your ice at 20 thousand times a second and you'll be on your way to making the first prototype of an ice-mediated radio.

Jokes aside, even though that's an old paper, trying to get a better understanding of water (and ice) is considered to be one of the biggest open questions in chemistry. One of the sort of "Holy Grails" of chemistry that hasn't yet been achieved (as far as I'm aware of) is using ultrafast spectroscopy to observe the behavior of water at a time-scale that modern theory cannot simulate.

And so, silly as it sounds, understanding the total dipole moment of water and ice is still a fairly relevant piece of interformation in modern research.

**EDIT:** As ZeroTheHero points out, the physical length of the dipole is large for macroscopic ice. Does this mean that this will break down the "far-field approximation" used to get the clean cosine formula for the dipole radiation?
Looking at the derivation of dipole radiation, it does seem there is an important [assumption that's made](http://www.phys.boun.edu.tr/%7Esevgena/p202/docs/Electric%20dipole%20radiation.pdf):

[image]

This means for the dipole radiation to be the case, we need to consider radiation that is of the frequency $\lambda >>length_{ice}$. If our ice is a few millimetres in size, this means we know we will get clean sine waves only for wavelengths much larger than millimeters in size. So if you want to [talk to radio-towers with this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_frequency):
[image]

you'll either potentially not get a clear signal or need to wiggle your ice up and down $10^8$ times per second to talk to a radiotower with it.
Alternatively, if you go very very far away with a very very large antenna, you'll be able to observe lower-frequency E-fields - but then you'll have to deal with a lot of noise, have an ultra sensitive detector and would probably have to do it in space to avoid your tiny signal from getting absorbed by air/structures/etc.

Comment: yet the dipole is not microscopic so would there not be phase difference between various “dipole” locations?

Comment: First I want to thank you for your appreciation, as I also believe the question to be of interest. Water is indeed a treasure of complexity and we still have much to learn about its properties. Secondly I am grateful of your research, this 1965 paper is enlightening and I will read it in its entirety before commenting further.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, this is a good point and added a section that tried to address this. I think as long as you oscillate your ice at the right frequency (and look sufficiently far away) the far-field approximations made in the derivation of dipole radiation still hold.

Comment: @Exocytosis, Glad I could help. It certainly is a creative, albeit strange idea - maybe some day a youtuber will attempt it for a goofy educational video. (Probably would be very hard though, so I don't recommend it!)